# Verifying a transaction

Tags: corda

I need some help understanding how the verification of a transaction works in Corda. If I understood correctly, all parties in a transaction are responsible for verifying it themselves.

I have a use case very similar to the [negotiation cordapp](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/negotiation-cordapp) between 2 parties. When writing a flow, I verify the unsigned transaction in the initiator:

```
// build the state that will be used as an output
val utx = TransactionBuilder(notary)
    .addInputState(input)
    .addOutputState(output)
    .addCommand(RequestContract.Commands.Accept(), output.participants.map { it.owningKey })

// verify the transaction against the smart contract
utx.verify(serviceHub)

// Sign the transaction.
val ptx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(utx, ourIdentity.owningKey)
```

In the responder, I need to verify the transaction as well.

```
val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(counterpartySession) {
    override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
        val state = stx.tx.outputStates.single() as RequestState
        requireThat {
            "Fulfilling a request has to be initiated by the fulfilling party" using (state.requestingParty == ourIdentity)
        }
    }
}

val stx = subFlow(signTransactionFlow)

// verify the transaction against the smart contract
stx.verify(serviceHub, checkSufficientSignatures = false)

return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(counterpartySession, stx.id))
```

Unless I set `checkSufficientSignatures = false`, I get an error that a signature is missing (`SignedTransaction$SignaturesMissingException`).

Why am I getting the error? I signed the transaction in the initiator and in the responder flow. How can I ensure that all signatures are present if I set `checkSufficientSignatures` to false? And lastly why doesn't the error show up when creating the `RequestState`, where both parties are signers as well and the flows are built pretty much identically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't see you calling `CollectSignaturesFlow` in the initiator; without that call, how are you going to ask the counter parties to sign?
2. No need to call `verify()` in the responder, if you open the code of `SignTransactionFlow()` you'll see [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/a1e1bf4e6d920d6943539e1675478d39c1004e8a/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/CollectSignaturesFlow.kt#L290) that when it receives the transaction; it resolves and verifies all of the transactions that lead to this transaction (including this one). So you can safely remove that call.

Comment: I call `CollectSignaturesFlow` right after signing, didn't want to include too much code in the example. I didn't know that I didn't need to call verify in the responder, thanks!